# How to split a string based on multiple words or sub strings

Tags: python, regex, string

I want to split a string in python based on multiple words, let's we have a SQL query

`select a1 from table1 as tb1 join table2 as tb2 on tb1.a2 = tb2.a2 where tb1.a3 = 'something'`

And now I want to split this string by `from`, `join`, `where` in one go and want to get a list of 

`{
select a1, 
table1 as tb1,
table2 as tb2 on tb1.a2 = tb2.a2,
tb1.a3 = 'something'
}`

Comment: `re.split(r'\s+(?:from|join|where)\s+', $str)`

Answer (score 3):

There is a built-in library for that:

```
import re

result = re.split('from|join|where', yourStr)
```

PS: @anubhava solution is better, which includes whitespaces to the determinators during the split.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`sqlparse`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sqlparse):

```
>>> import sqlparse
>>> sql = "select a1 from table1 as tb1 join table2 as tb2 on tb1.a2 = tb2.a2 wher
e tb1.a3 = 'something'"
>>> formatted_sql = sqlparse.format(sql, reindent=True, keyword_case='lower')
>>> formatted_sql
"select a1\nfrom table1 as tb1\njoin table2 as tb2 on tb1.a2 = tb2.a2\nwhere tb1.a3 = 'something'"
>>> formatted_sql.split('\n')
['select a1', 'from table1 as tb1', 'join table2 as tb2 on tb1.a2 = tb2.a2', "where tb1.a3 = 'something'"]
```

Where you can format the SQL query with `sqlparse.format()`, which gives back your query with `\n` characters inserted. Then you can just split on newlines to obtain your desired list.

You can install this module with `pip install sqlparse`.